# CucumberOptions cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber

In my testrunner class, on using `@CucumberOptions`, I am getting an error message saying "CucumberOptions cannot be resolved to a type". I am using the latest version of eclipse cucumber dependencies. I have tried every possible way by installing and uninstalling eclipse, by lowering the cucumber dependencies version.

My runner class is :

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.*;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;    

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        // format = {"pretty","html:target/html/" } ,
        features = "src/test/resources", glue = "com.cucumber.bhsibase.party.tests")
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

And my POM.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>BHSI_BASE</groupId>
    <artifactId>BHSI_BASE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BHSI_BASE</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependencies added for testng start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependencies added for testng completed -->

        <!-- dependencies on cucumber jarss -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependencies on log4j jarss -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please let me know how to proceed ahead with this .

Comment: You do not have the following class import listed: `import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;`

Comment: On adding that I was getting "The import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions cannot be resolved" error .

Comment: Eclipse is quite special regarding Maven. After running `mvn clean install` to compile a project, you also need to run `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` to update the Eclipse configuration of the project.

Comment: did it and restated but still the same . Some how it works fine with my system fine at home . But the same code here doesnt work .

Comment: Do you actually have the Cucumber dependencies downloaded?

Answer (score 6):

I met the same issue. cucumber-java 1.2.2 is working for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is outdated.

Assuming you are either doing a new project or don't rely on any related legacy version code.

Now you need

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
```

in maven pom.xml, and replace the 7.0.0 to the most recent version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
```

Most probably both are not getting resolved.

Solution:

1. Step 1: Change scope of cucumber-junit from
   test to compile.
2. Step 2:  In your Test runner class

**Import Below:**

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
```

Instead of :

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
```

**Working for me**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the scope from the dependency. That resolved the issue for me.

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

Following should be your dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>7.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Resolve this import - import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

add the below maven dependency-

info.cukes
    cucumber-core`
1.2.5

Comment: If you are using cucumber with JUnit and import not resolved for this - import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;  then change the scope of this dependency at Compile level instead of Test. <dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.5</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with Cucumber (it's end of Nov, 2021 and I believe that the version is newer than the answer) and I am following [this document](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/README.md). Please also check their skeleton pom file [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/pom.xml) for the dependencies.

The setup is now use

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("com/example")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.example")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

and for the `@CucumberOptions`, you can use `junit-platform.properties` to config.

For more details about the properties configuration, you can find [here](http://junit-platform.properties)

I also have [an example](https://github.com/tuanmhoang/testing/tree/main/bdd-cucumber) if you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this dependency:

tech.grasshopper
extentreports-cucumber6-adapter
2.1.0

Answer (score -1):

This option worked out very well.

- import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; then change the scope of this dependency at Compile level instead of Test.  info.cukes cucumber-junit 1.2.5 compile

Comment: The Cucumber dependencies should be defined in scope "test". You don't want/need the dependency in your release code and I also think this is not the solution for the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue and resolved the error by including following maven dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks.